# Nodejs MySQL connection timeout

Tags: node.js

When I run the application, It shows me `Database is connected!`

**db.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var settings = require('./config');
var db;
var exports = {};

exports.connectdb = function () {

 db = mysql.createConnection(settings.Database);

 db.connect(function(err){

     console.log('connecting');
     if(!err) {
         console.log('Database is connected!');
         return db;
     } else {
         console.log('Error connecting database!'+err);
         return null;
     }
 });

};

module.exports = exports;
```

but when i am trying to connect DB from user.js it shows me `connection is null` / `TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined`.

code block from **user.js**

```
var exports = {};
var dbcon = require('../config/db.js');
var dbconn = dbcon.connectdb();

exports.login = function(email,password) {

var userdetails = { name:email, password:password};

var dbconn = dbcon.connectdb();
if ( dbconn == null ) console.log('still nul');


dbconn.query("SELECT * FROM users where email = '"+email+"' and password = '"+password +"'", function (err, result) {
    if(err)
    {
        console.log(result[0]+' err');
        return null;
    }
});
};

module.exports = exports;
```

Comment: Can you post more code in your user.js file? Preferably, to include your require statements.

Comment: yes! check it now

Comment: i think it connect for the first time.. when i load application... but when i try to login through select query that time connection variable is empty.. so i make an object of db then call connect function ..... my connectdb function it called but db.connect() inside function is not showing any result.. example ( "error connecting DB" OR "Database is connected!" )

Comment: I posted an answer. Let me know if that works for you or if you have additional questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js is asynchronous by nature. You are trying to use it in a synchronous fashion. To make this work, you must use the callback pattern.  Below is an example:

**db.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var settings = require('./config');
var exports = {};

exports.connectdb = function (callback) {

 var db = mysql.createConnection(settings.Database);

 db.connect(function(err){
     callback(err,db);
 });

};

module.exports = exports;
```

**user.js**

```
var exports = {};
var dbcon = require('../config/db.js');

exports.login = function(email,password) {

    var userdetails = { name:email, password:password};

    dbcon.connectdb(function(err, dbconn){
        if ( err) //handle error


        dbconn.query("SELECT * FROM users where email = '"+email+"' and password = '"+password +"'", function (err, result) {
        if(err)
        {
           console.log(result[0]+' err');
        }
        });
    });
};

module.exports = exports;
```

From the code above you can see how the `connectdb` function accepts a function callback. When the database is connected the code will execute that callback to send the results. In  the user.js file, you can now pass a callback function and use the results it gives you (the db). You can find more info about Node.js' asynchronous nature [here](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/). Basically, asynchronous code uses callbacks and synchronous code uses `return` statements. Returning values from asynchronous functions will most always yield null results as asynchronous callbacks will always fire "sometime" after the function is called.

Comment: TypeError: callback is not a function

Comment: That means that `callback` you passed is not a function. Do you know where that error is coming from? The code I posted doesn't appear to have any errors.

Comment: i am new to nodeJS but when i am trying to call callback function after connect() it is obvious i don't have any call back function that why it showing me error, also let me know if you have any example of login system

Comment: When you call `dbcon.connectdb(function(err, dbconn){ ...`, the `function` is the `callback` referenced in db.js on the line `exports.connectdb = function (callback) {`. So, `callback` is a function and it is being used correctly in the example. Can you update your code example with what you have?

Comment: In the user.js you posted above. you still did not change the code. In your example you have `var dbconn = dbcon.connectdb();` and in mine I have `dbcon.connectdb(function(err, dbconn){ ...`. You need to update your code using my example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129061/discussion-between-syed-daniyal-asif-and-corey-berigan).